# Slanted edge MTF evaluation with ImageJ plugin

Tags: imagej

I am trying to evaluate an optical system by calculating the MTF with the slanted edge method. For this I use the following ImageJ plugin:
https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/plugins/se-mtf/index.html

No I want to calculate the MTF with the frequency units "lp/mm". For this I have to insert the "Sensor size (mm)" and the "Number of photodetectors". Sadly I cannot find any description and what these values are exactly. If I use the diagonal of the sensor in mm and the number of pixels my sensor has as the second value, I get nonsense values (very high frequencies, higher than 100000 lp/mm).
Does anyone have experience with this tool and can give me a hint on what values I need here?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am also not 100% sure but I guess its the sensor width and the number of pixels along the sensor width

Comment: If you are not sure don't post an answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The 2 input values are just there to fix the scale, even it could have been reduced to 1 = xx µm/mm.
So, "Sensor size (mm)" = whatever size (mm) in the image considered, just choose it coherent with the real size of the image (just for logic).
Then, "Number of photodetectors" = the number (qty) of Voxels corresponding to this "whatever size (mm)" input above.
Then ImageJ is having the scale into the image made of Voxel.
Last but not least, 2 things : (1) do not forget in your ROI selection (square) that void shall be on the Left Hand side ; (2) The more accurate result is obtained when material wall is vertical on your image (otherwise, when bended, you will have bias vs.vertical wall.

Answer (score 0):

The creator's answer to a similar question:
Hello everyone and thanks to the creators of the plug in.
I have to analyze the mammography image and I cannot run the option lp/mm, using (SE_MTF_2xNyquist)
The sensor, flat panel, has a size of 236.4 mm (vertical) x 296.4 mm (horizontal)
The number of output brushes 4728 (vertical) x 5928 (horizontal) = 28 027 584 brushes
14 bits of output.
Resolution in brushes 50 x 50 μm / pix.
What size value of the censor I put

ANSWER: All do you need to note is one sensor side size (mm) and the number of corresponding pixels (pix) in this given side. The plug-in will calculate the resolution in lp/mm as the frequency unit in the MTF plot. Some sensors have different resolution for vertical or horizontal directions. You can always calculate the MTF of each direction using the corresponding sensor size (mm) and number of pixels (pix) on this given side. The Nyquist frequency corresponds to 0.5 cycles/pix. Beyond this frequency you can observe the amount of aliasing present. Hope this help.